# AWS S3 object permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an image in my S3 Bucket. When I click download image it downloads fine but when i click on the link of image it says `Access Denied` 
[image]

I have allowed both read and write permission to public.

[image]

What else I should do to make this image accessible by public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your picture of the console is showing permissions assigned to your Amazon S3 **bucket**, not the object itself. Such permissions only grant access to **list the contents** of a bucket, or **upload** to a bucket.

If you wish to **grant public access for that specific object**, then:

- Click the **Objects** tab
- Tick the object you wish to modify
- Click the **Permissions** tab
- Select **Everyone**, then **Object Access**, then tick **Read**
- Click **Save**

The link should now work for public access.

However, if you wish to **grant public access for all objects in the bucket**, use a Bucket Policy such as [Granting Read-Only Permission to an Anonymous User](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2). This can also be used to grant public access to a particular directory/path within a bucket.